# Indexes using datagidx where multiple terms have a single index entry

Tags: beamer, indexing, datatool

I'm building off of [an example here from the LaTeX Community](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=22841&p=77510).

What I want to do is create an index where multiple terms link to the same word in the index. So for example if the terms `toyota`, `ford`, and `honda`, appear on pages `7`, `9` and `15` I want the index simply say:

```
cars … 7, 9, 15
```

What I don't want is

```
cars,
toyota … 7
ford … 9
honda …15
```

I'm doing this in `beamer`. And the following example will create the term `cars`, but I don't know how to associate multiple words with that single term.

```
\documentclass[16pt,pdftex]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
% beamer doesn't define \@idxitem, but it's used by the
% \printterms "index" style, so define it:
\newcommand\@idxitem{\par\hangindent40pt}
\makeatother

\usepackage{datagidx}

\newgidx{index}{Index}
\DTLgidxSetDefaultDB{index}

\newterm{car}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{example}
\gls{car}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{example}
%\gls{subaru}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{example}
%\gls{toyota}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{example}
%\gls{ford}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Index}
\printterms[style=index]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have at least version 2.19 of `datatool` installed and use `\glslink`:

```
\documentclass[16pt,pdftex]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
% beamer doesn't define \@idxitem, but it's used by the
% \printterms "index" style, so define it:
\newcommand\@idxitem{\par\hangindent40pt}
\makeatother

\usepackage{datagidx}

\newgidx{index}{Index}
\DTLgidxSetDefaultDB{index}

\newterm{car}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{example}
\gls{car}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{example}
\glslink{car}{subaru}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{example}
\gls{car}{toyota}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{example}
\glslink{car}{ford}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Index}
\printterms[style=index]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```